# Spring boot and springfox-swagger2 - $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs - Solution provided

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

If you’re using the springfox-swagger2 library, you might come across a problem when it comes to generic types. In cases where diamond brackets are used, Swagger will generate an invalid specification, resulting in a validation error in the Swagger Editor (“”$ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs”).

The error you get might look like this:

> Semantic error at paths./v1/car.post.parameters.0.schema.$ref
> $ref values must be RFC3986-compliant percent-encoded URIs
> Jump to line 45

Comment: It is quite OK to ask a question and then answer it yourself. It is not clear from what you posted what the original configuration and which part of the Docket is the solution.

Comment: I upvoted your question, but what I meant is you leave your question as a question, then you add the solution as an answer below, otherwise it doesn't look like there is an answer when searching.

Answer (score 4):

Solution of the problem I found under [Springfox documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#changing-how-generic-types-are-named)

> By default, types with generics will be labeled with '\u00ab'(<<), '\u00bb'(>>), and commas. This can be problematic with things like swagger-codegen. You can override this behavior by implementing your own GenericTypeNamingStrategy. For example, if you wanted List to be encoded as 'ListOfString' and Map<String, Object> to be encoded as 'MapOfStringAndObject' you could set the forCodeGeneration customization option to true during plugin customization:
> `docket.forCodeGeneration(true|false);`

Here’s an example Docket configuration with the added change:

```
@Configuration    
@EnableSwagger2
public class CommonConfiguration {

   @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .enableUrlTemplating(false)
                .forCodeGeneration(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer when we need the documentation in OAS3 specs as it converts documentation to OAS 2 specs.